# How to get information about any user having only user_id in telegram bot in Java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I use Java and [telegrambots](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots) library. Using the [keyboardButtonRequestUser](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbuttonrequestuser) method, I can get the user_id of an outside user, but how to collect all the information about outside user with only the user_id?

```
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {

            String massageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            User user = update.getMessage().getFrom();

            if (massageText.equals("/start")) {
// UserShared --> UserShared(requestId=732633638, userId=6165875618)
                System.out.println("OutsideUserId = 6165875618 --> " + "...????");

                startCommandReceived(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
            } 
            else {
                sendMessage(chatId, "Sorry, command was not recognized");
            }

        } 
        else if (update.hasMessage()){
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            sendMessage(chatId, "UserShared --> "+ update.getMessage().getUserShared());
            sendMessage(chatId, "ChatShared --> "+ update.getMessage().getChatShared());
            sendMessage(chatId, "CurrentChatId --> "+chatId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but in my opinion this is impossible because we can only request user data when he enters the robot. Anybody have a different opinion on this?